# Question about ssh on 14.04 with Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 14.04, ssh

When trying to connect via ssh with nautilus Ubuntu 14.04, if you do not specify the folder to which you want to access does not show me any directory.

So if I want to connect to any folder system like `/etc` I would specify the path to ssh `:"IP"/etc` so if you access, but if I want to move above can not.

So to connect to the root of a system should specify ssh `:/"IP"/`, which gives an error.

Instead it will automatically in Ubuntu 12.04 gives you the `/` as the default route, watching the whole directory tree.

Anyone know anything or tried to? Because if you want to go on moving files I need to stay on `/` to see all of them.

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get when you try to connect to the root folder?

Comment: paths via ssh are usually specified as `hostname:/path/to/dir`

Comment: I'm on the same boat here, it's rather annoying. When I connect to sftp://hostname/ it will not send me to the root, just the user home folder as ssh normally would, with no option to go up a folder. They really should put `..` as a clickable folder option.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, have you tried syntax like this?

```
sftp://azendale@10.0.0.1/
```

`sftp` stands for "SSH File Transfer Protocol" which is designed for handling files over SSH.

Or you could go to a subfolder, and then try hitting Ctrl-L. Then remove the trailing folder. That's what I usually do.